# I used sprintf(), why does VC++ complain about _swprintf()?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

VC++2019 rejects my statement `sprintf(subjectId, "%s", imageInfo->name);` by error message:

> error C2664: 'int _swprintf(wchar_t *const ,const wchar_t *const ,...)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'char [50]' to 'wchar_t *const'

where the type of `imageInfo->name` is `char *`, and `subjectId` is char array (`char subjectId[50]`).

My VC++ configuration of Character Set is "Use Unicode Character Set". But I must use narrow characters because the message passed to me is in narrow character. As I know, even in case of Wide Character Set, `sprintf()` can still be used. Besides, I called `sprintf()`, why does it complain about `_swprintf()`?

Comment: Probably Microsoft playing macro games again. I don't have any good documented reason to suggest this, but see what happens if you replace `sprintf` with `_sprintf`

Comment: My addtional comment: Do not use any printf function in C++

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](https://rextester.com/HNOVA26345).

Comment: Please post the exact code you have in ``FRV_Dll.cp`` on line 336.

Comment: sprintf(subjectId, "%s", imageInfo->name);

Comment: @StanHuangatTaiwan The error [doesn't happen](https://rextester.com/HNOVA26345) with that line of code alone, and no one can guess what's different in your real code if you don't post it. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For a long shot, does it make a difference if you insert an `#undef sprintf` before that call?

Answer (score -1):

If you select "Use Unicode Character Set", it uses the Unicode character set. C-style strings are now held in `TCHAR` (which is identical to `WCHAR` which is identical to `wchar_t`) instead of `char`.

If you don't want these transformations, don't ask for them.

You can find more information on the Microsoft page about [Unicode and Multibyte Character Set Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/unicode-and-multibyte-character-set-mbcs-support?view=msvc-160).

Comment: So, if I turn on that option `"Hello"` becomes `L"Hello"`? There is no way this is allowed by the standard.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili The standard doesn't (nor could it) prohibit compilers from giving you options that change the compiler's behavior in ways that are different from what the standard requires. If you don't find them useful, then don't use them. You certainly don't have to use unicode or UTF-16 if you don't want to. In practice, there's no way to make this work within the standard because `sizeof(char)` is 1 no matter what and having your sizeof return sizes in two-byte words is awful.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili No, `"Hello"` never becomes `L"Hello"`. But if you use Microsoft's macros then `TEXT("Hello")` will translate to either `"Hello"` or `L"Hello"` depending on the `_UNICODE` compile.

Comment: @dxiv that's not what this answer says. The question doesn't use the `TEXT` macro either.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili See the [`TEXT` macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text) and [Unicode Programming Summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/text/unicode-programming-summary?view=msvc-160) for the `_T` and `_TEXT` macros. There is no automatic translation between narrow and wide characters if you don't use those macros. As for OP's question, I believe something may be missing there.

Comment: @dxiv I am familiar with those macros. This answer claims that turning on some option will turn all c-string literals to wide string literals. I have not tested that, but it would explain OP's problem.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Not quite sure what option @DavidSchwartz refers to, but it's not (just) the "*Use Unicode Character Set*". What I see in [this link](https://rextester.com/HNOVA26345) with `/DUNICODE /D_UNICODE` is what I see when running the same code in my VC++ inside a default wizard-generated C++ console app with the default settings, which include "*Use Unicode Character Set*". It does *not* match what the OP describes in the question. You can try it and verify for yourself.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I think you're misunderstanding the answer. I'm talking about what `sprintf` expects with this option (and perhaps others) turned on.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `sprintf` is always the narrow version. The "*generic-text*" version is [`_stprintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-sprintf-l-swprintf-swprintf-l-swprintf-l?view=msvc-160), which I suspect the OP might be using (or, at least, *that* one would explain what they describe).

Comment: @dxiv You can see from the question that a call to `sprintf` wound up trying to pass his first argument to a function that expects a `wchar_t * const`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The OP has yet to produce actual code that duplicates the error, so it's anybody's guess what they might be doing. Meanwhile, the documentation clearly states that [`sprintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-sprintf-l-swprintf-swprintf-l-swprintf-l?view=msvc-160) works with narrow strings, and a simple [code snippet](https://rextester.com/HNOVA26345) verifies that. If you have evidence to the contrary then by all means please post it, but just stating that `sprintf` is somehow different in Unicode builds doesn't make it so.

Comment: @dxiv The evidence is in the question. The OP called `sprintf` and got an error that the first parameter needs to be of type `wchar_t * const`. If you think the question is wrong, take it up with the person who asked it. I'm just answering the question asked.